# Summoning awakened monsters with summoning pieces

Tags: summoners-war

Is it possible to summon a 4* monster using summoning pieces.

Say you get the 50 pieces for the mermaid HoH, and you go to the Stonehenge, and select her for summoning. Can lightning show and give you a Tetra?

Comment: It might be super super rare, but I've never gotten it.

Comment: I can provide the math for any summon, except those monster pieces.. so I'm certain this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to summon a awakened monster with summoning pieces.